# Volume of intersection of unit $n$-sphere and $n$-cone (or how to evaluate $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_{\phi_i=0}^t \sin^{n-i-1}(\phi_i)\,d\phi_{i}$)

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, volume, spheres

I wish to find the volume, $v_n$, of intersection between a unit $n$-sphere and a solid $n$-dimensional right circular cone whose height is larger than $1$ and whose aperture is $\theta<\pi.$

From [this section of the wiki-article for an $n$-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element), I've concluded (perhaps incorrectly) that this should be given by

\begin{align}
v_n(\theta)=\int_{\phi_1=0}^\theta\int_{\phi_2=0}^\theta\cdots \int_{\phi_{n-1}=0}^\theta\int_{r=0}^1 \mathrm{d}^nV,
\end{align}

where 
$$\mathrm{d}^nV=r^{n-1} \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\phi_2)\cdots \sin^1(\phi_{n-2})\sin^0(\phi_{n-1})\,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\phi_{1}\,\mathrm{d}\phi_{2} \cdots \,\mathrm{d}\phi_{n-1}.$$

We can simplify the notation a bit:

$$v_n(\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_{\phi_i=0}^\theta \sin^{n-i-1}(\phi_i)\,\mathrm{d}\phi_{i}.$$

> If this is the correct expression, how can it be evaluated?
>
> If it isn't the correct expression, what then is, and how can *that* be evaluated?
>
> **Or is there an easier way?** (Perhaps involving "trimming down" the volume of an $n$-cone with height $1$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Cavalieri's theorem looks easier: Let $c_{n}$ denote the [volume of the unit ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) in $\Reals^{n}$, so that a ball of radius $\rho$ has $n$-dimensional volume $c_{n} \rho^{n}$.

If $x$ is a Cartesian coordinate along the cone axis with its origin at the vertex, each hyperplane orthogonal to the $x$-axis cuts your solid in an $(n-1)$-ball whose radius is
$$
\rho = \begin{cases}
  x\tan\theta & 0 \leq x \leq \cos\theta, \\
  \sqrt{1 - x^{2}} & \cos\theta < x \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Consequently, the volume of your object is
\begin{multline*}
\int_{0}^{\cos\theta} c_{n-1}(x\tan\theta)^{n-1}\, dx + \int_{\cos\theta}^{1} c_{n-1} (1 - x^{2})^{(n-1)/2}\, dx \\
= c_{n-1} \left[\frac{\sin^{n-1}\theta \cos\theta}{n} + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{n} \phi\, d\phi\right].
\end{multline*}
The second integral can, at worst, be handled using the reduction formula
$$
\int \cos^{n}\phi\, d\phi
= \frac{1}{n}\left[\cos^{n-1}\phi \sin\phi + (n-1) \int \cos^{n-2}\phi\, d\phi\right].
$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm having trouble implementing your answer, though. For instance for $n=2$ and $\theta=\frac{2}{3}\pi$ I get a "volume" (area) of $\frac{2}{3}\pi,$ but by hand I get $\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1}{3}\pi.$ What do you get? Are you perhaps defining the aperture differently than I?

Comment: Ah, yes: Implicitly I was taking $\theta \leq \pi/2$. If $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$, subtract the "complementary" volume from the volume of the unit ball. For $\theta = 2\pi/3$, the complementary angle is $\pi/3$; the formula gives an area of $\pi/3$, so the correct area is $\pi - \pi/3 = 2\pi/3$. (This is "expected": If $\theta = 2\pi/3$, the wedge subtends an angle $2\theta = 4\pi/3$. :)

Comment: So, just to be clear, if we call the volume you calculated in your answer $v_n$, then $c_n-v_n$ would be the appropriate expression when $\pi/2<\theta < \pi$?

Comment: Yes (provided you also replace $\theta$ with $\pi - \theta$).

Comment: I think making the substitution $\theta \rightarrow \pi - \theta$ is enough (so that shouldn't be subtracted from $c_n$, I think)? .. At least that gives the correct result for the example (when plugging it into Mathematica).

Comment: I'm skeptical: The solid with $0 < \theta < \pi/2$ is less than half the ball, so its complement has larger volume (the sum of the volumes is $c_{n}$). Incidentally, the splitting of the integral on the left works for $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ (the first integral runs right to left if $\pi/2 < \theta$, so the effect is to subtract the volume of a cone from a "zone" of the unit ball), but to get the second integral on the right one needs $\arcsin(\cos\theta) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$, which is true only if $\theta < \pi/2$.

Comment: You are probably right. My confusion arises due to the assumptions I give when evaluating in Mathematica. I write: 
f[n_, t_] = 
  Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0 && Element[t, Reals] && 
    Pi/2 < t < Pi, Integrate[Cos[x]^n, {x, t - Pi/2, Pi/2}]];

cn[n_] = Pi^(n/2)/Gamma[n/2 + 1];

g[n_, t_] = 
 cn[n - 1]*(Sin[(Pi - t)]^(n - 1)*Cos[(Pi - t)]/n + f[n, t])

and when evaluating g[2, 2/3 Pi], it gives me the desired $\pi/3.$ Note that I didn't subtract the volume from that of the unit sphere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still having a hard time getting the correct results: If I implement your original formula for $n=2,\theta=\pi/4,$ it should be obvious that the result should be $\pi/8,$ but I get $\pi/4$ from your formula instead. Do you have any ideas as to what might be going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: My apology: What I've been calling $\theta$ is _one-half_ the aperture. (From habit, I measure cone angles from the axis to a generator....) Please ask if that doesn't reconcile my formulas and your calculations.

Comment: That seemed to do it! That also made it clear why you assumed $\theta\leq \pi/2$ - of course the cone is convex! What I meant I was interested in was  the aperture going from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ and that is covered by your original range of $\theta$. Thanks again, now it all works like a charm (and I can get on with my bachelor's thesis!) :D